# How do I apply Autoresizing to Interface Builder in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, tvos

I want to apply Autoresizing settings to a view in Interface Builder, but that settings panel isn't available in the Size inspector.  How do I make this work in Xcode 9.2?

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder removes the Autoresizing panel from the Size inspector if there are any Layout Constraints applied to that view or one of its subviews.  Delete all Layout Constraints from that view's descending hierarchy, and the Autoresizing settings reappear.

(Discovered from reading between the lines of [this article](http://www.thomashanning.com/xcode-8-mixing-auto-autoresizing-masks/).)

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Xcode we can see the "Autoresizing panel" in Size Inspector if "Auto Constraints are already checked.

But if still you are facing this issue then you can get Autoresizing panel settings in Size Inspector after unchecking the "Auto Constraints" settings. Then you will be able to see the "Autoresizing panel" in size inspector

You can check the attached screenshots which is as follows:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/psQgh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nsji.png